# How to connect to Microsoft Access Database from another computer through odbc_connect()?

Tags: php, ms-access, odbc

I'm making an attendance system via Pollo PLF-1000 finger print device and it uses microsoft access db (mdb) which is stored on server computer. How can i access the server Access DB from my local computer for development?

odbc_connect("DRIVER={MICROSOFT ACCESS DRIVER (*.mdb)}; Dbq=\192.168.5.109\file.mdb");

[image]

Comment: Is `\192.168.5.109\file.mdb` supposed to be a UNC file share path? If so it should be `\\192.168.5.109\file.mdb` - UNC paths are expressed as `\\server\share`, with two backslashes at the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To diagnose your specific issue, do the following:

1. **Verify Installed ODBC Drivers**: Open Powershell and run [`Get-OdbcDriver`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/wdac/get-odbcdriver?view=win10-ps) to verify installed drivers where output will list drivers in either 32/64-bit installations.
2. **Determine PHP Bit Version**: Either use `PHP_INT_SIZE` (4 being 32-bit and 8 being 64-bit) or `php_info` page, or still other means available on online search.

As information, `.mdb` is the older version of Microsoft Access databases. The latest version starting in 2007 is `.accdb`. With this change, ODBC drivers changed as well:

- `Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)` is the 32-bit installed ODBC driver. If your PHP is a 32-bit installation, it can access this driver.
- `Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)` is the 64-bit installed ODBC driver. Notice it can access both versions of Access databases. If your PHP is a 64-bit installation, it can access this driver.

Finally, be sure to follow case sensitivity of driver name and correctly point to Windows network directories including local or UNC paths. Sometimes it may be better to map networked paths to a letter drive. Avoid WAN connections and non-Windows environments.